# Software that annotates audio and video files

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, audio, annotations

I am looking for free or inexpensive software that I can watch video or listen to audio files and annotate what is happening as I watch.  I am looking for something akin to audacity's label track but in a simpler application that also supports video.

We don't need to edit the video or audio itself.  It needs to be able to run on windows 7.  Also if possible to have a setting where every 20 seconds the playback pauses to allow for annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try open-source [Advene](http://liris.cnrs.fr/advene/index.html) and look for [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/advene/?license=opensource) like open-source Scripto and TranscriberAG, or free VoiceWalker.

[download Advene](http://liris.cnrs.fr/advene/download.html)

Advene screenshots

[image: ss0]
[image: ss1]

You find more info and homepage for each program at the 'alternatives' site I linked.